# htaccess query string redirect to path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a url like about.php?lang=en and I want to change it to about.php/en 
I have tried

```
<pre>
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /\?(([^&\s]*&)*)lang=([^&\s]+)&?([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lang/%3?%1%4 [L,R=301]
</pre>
```

In htaccess but it doen't work.

Comment: isnt this for apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
#redirect /about.php?lang=lang to /about.php/lang
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /about\.php\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /about.php/%1? [L,R]
#internally forward /about.php/lang to /about.php?lang=lang
RewriteRule ^about\.php/([^/]+)/?$ /about.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Dont remove the final **?** otherwise mod-rewrite will append old querystring to the destination url.

Comment: this seems to be working but now I am getting 404 page is there any way that we change the url in the browser

Comment: and not redirect the page

Comment: Ok, i have added a new rule to handle the uri.

Comment: Thanks starkeen that was perfact